# Event Tracking in C#

Tags: c#, events, bug-tracking, sequence

I want to understand event cycles.  I have a form with a grid and textboxes.  It has a grid, bound to DataTable, and textboxes bound to same table too.  I'm trying to debug something and need to know how to identify ALL events fired in the form to see what may solve an issue for me.

Anyhow, unless I explicitly subclass every class on my form, and override / attach to every event to my own event handlers, how can I get / listen to all events being fired during a certain action...  Such as changing a "Selected" road in a DataGridView.  It obviously updates its own "CurrentRow"...   I need to know what / how to maybe FORCE a re-loading of SAME CurrentRow.

Reason:  during a form level "Edit Mode", and I change the content in another "Textbox" control, and reject changes, I need it to simulate the current "Record" is reloaded to go back to its original values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could fire up a profiler and look at the method call tree.